# Map Nested Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have here a nested array. The inner array has only one data.
Is there a way that I would improve this? Like minimize using `[0]`?
Using modern JS.

NOTE: I rename status to myStatus

```js
let response = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Hello",
                "status": "There"
            }
        ],
    
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Hello",
                "status": "There"
            }
        ],
    
    }
];


const finalDatas = response?.map((value) => {
 return {
   name: value?.data?.[0]?.name,
   myStatus: value?.data?.[0]?.status
 };
});
      
console.log(finalDatas)
```

Comment: you could just do `map((v) => v.data[0])`...or `map((v) => v.data.shift())`, but this will change the original array

Comment: Without renaming `const finalDatas = response.flatMap(({data}) => [...data]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
const response = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Hello",
                "status": "There"
            }
        ],
    
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Hello",
                "status": "There"
            }
        ],
    
    },
    {
        "data": [ // name: undefined, status: null
            {
                "status": null
            }
        ],
    
    },
    {
        "data": [ // data array with empty object
            {}
        ],
    },
{
        "data": [], //empty array - this doesn't end up in the result list
    },
];

const res = response.flatMap(({data}) => [...data].map(item => {
    return {
      name: item.name,
      myStatus: item.status,
    };
}));
console.log(res);
```

EDIT: I added more cases to the snippet. As you can see this code produces an entry in the result list as long there is an object inside the data list.

Comment: Does handle if some data are undefined or null? Also,  I want to maintain the `return`

Comment: @Joseph I updated the data used in this example. Have a look at the output an see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Good. Also I want to maintain the `return` just like in my question above. return { ...}

Comment: I mean inside of `.map`. I want to put the `return { ...}`

Comment: Please check again @Joseph

Comment: Thank you. Can we use just one return. Just the `return` inside of `.map`?

Comment: @Joseph changed it, please accept this answer if it's what you've been looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatMap and a spread

Without renaming

```
const finalDatas = response.flatMap(({data}) => [...data]);
```

UPDATE after comment:
the code needs to be somewhere

```js
const ren = (obj, oldKey, newKey) => {
  obj = obj.pop();
  return delete Object.assign(obj, {[newKey]: obj[oldKey]})[oldKey], obj;
}
const finalDatas = response.map(({data}) => ren(data, "status", "myStatus"));

console.log(finalDatas);
```

```html
<script>
  let response = [{
      "data": [{
        "name": "Hello",
        "status": "There"
      }],

    },
    {
      "data": [{
        "name": "Hello",
        "status": "There"
      }],

    }
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: I'm renaming `tatus` instead of `status`.

Comment: No that wasn't. That's why I did use `return`

Comment: Don't wanna use `pop` as it old feature and I want to maintain the `return`

Answer (score 0):

try with the below code snippet. This might be helpful.

```js
    let response = [
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Hello",
                "status": "There"
            }
        ],
    
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Hello",
                "status": "There"
            }
        ],
    
    }
];

let renameKey = ( obj, oldKey, newKey ) => {
  obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
  delete obj[oldKey];
  return obj
}

let output = response.map(data => renameKey(data.data[0], "status", "myStatus"));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Still has [0] and no renaming

Comment: Can you add a sample output of the JSON?

Comment: Not my question. Look at OP's snippet output

Comment: Hi, I have modified above code to rename status to myStatus. Pls check